# ExpandableListview: adding a clicklistener for an imageview in a child row while keeping row onitemclick

Tags: android, list, xamarin, click, listeners

I have a ExpandableListView. In these listviews there are group and child views.
In a childview, there's an ImageView.

When i add a clicklistener in the adapter for the imageview, the listener for OnChildClicked (on the listview) doesn't work anymore

How can I listen to both ClickEvents?
Adding onclick on a the indicatorIv itself is also good, but then i need the groupposition and childposition somehow, and i don't know how to do this

this is the eventhandler for tagList.ChildClick :

```
void TagList_ChildClick (object sender, ExpandableListView.ChildClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (adapter.IsIndicatorClicked()) 
        //{
            TagVO tag = tagsCollection [e.GroupPosition].Tags [e.ChildPosition];

            tag.Selected = !tag.Selected;
            if (tag.Selected) 
            {
                _mySelectionController.SaveLocalTag (tag);
            } 
            else
                _mySelectionController.RemoveLocalTag (tag);


            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();
        //} else

    }
```

The GetChildView method in the adapter: see "Console.Writeline("test")
(this method is fired, the handler above is not)

```
 public override View GetChildView (int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        TagHolder tagHolder=null;
        TagVO tag = tags [groupPosition].Tags [childPosition];

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.tagListItem, null);
            tagHolder = new TagHolder ();

            tagHolder.AddTagBtn = convertView.FindViewById<ViewGroup> (Resource.Id.addTagBtn);
            tagHolder.TagIndicatorBtn = convertView.FindViewById<ViewGroup> (Resource.Id.tagIndicator);
            tagHolder.TagNameTv = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.tagNameTv);
            tagHolder.tagIndicatorIv = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.tagIndicatorIv);
            tagHolder.tagIndicatorIv.Click+= delegate 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("test");  
            };

            tagHolder.TagNameTv.SetTypeface (TypeFaceLoader.get (_activity.ApplicationContext, "fonts/DINPro-Regular.otf"),Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Normal);

            convertView.Tag = tagHolder;
        } 
        else 
        {
            tagHolder = (TagHolder) convertView.Tag;
        }

        tagHolder.TagNameTv.Text = tag.Name;

        if (tags [groupPosition].Tags [childPosition].Selected) 
        {
            tagHolder.AddTagBtn.SetBackgroundColor (Color.ParseColor ("#44c4d1"));
            tagHolder.TagIndicatorBtn.SetBackgroundColor (Color.ParseColor ("#44c4d1"));
            tagHolder.TagNameTv.SetTextColor (Color.White);
            tagHolder.tagIndicatorIv.SetImageDrawable(_activity.Resources.GetDrawable( Resource.Drawable.check));
        } 
        else 
        {
            tagHolder.AddTagBtn.SetBackgroundDrawable (_activity.Resources.GetDrawable( Resource.Drawable.articleBg));
            tagHolder.TagIndicatorBtn.SetBackgroundDrawable (_activity.Resources.GetDrawable( Resource.Drawable.articleBg));
            tagHolder.TagNameTv.SetTextColor (Color.ParseColor ("#848484"));
            tagHolder.tagIndicatorIv.SetImageDrawable(_activity.Resources.GetDrawable( Resource.Drawable.plus));
        }



        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Show us what your code is and we can help you better. Otherwise, we would just be speculating on what is going wrong.